# How to add another image to the right of an image in column with HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to add an image (img src="~/img/logo2.jpg) next to below image in a different column.

```
<header class="header overlay"
        id="core_view_Header_0"
        style="display: block;">
    <!-- visible bar -->
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table style="width: 100%">
        <table style="display: <inline-block>;">
        <table style="float: left;">   
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a class="logo" href="#" target="" tabindex="12">
                        <img src="~/img/logo1.png">
                    </a>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem, you could put the image in its own paragraph with nothing to its left or right (except maybe another image):

The other option is to tell the web browser to push the graphic all the way to the left or right and make the text fill in NEXT to it, as the cat graphic to the right is doing here.

This is the code you need to align an image to the right:

```html
**<img src="http://www.example.com/graphic.jpg" style="float: right;** margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;"**>**
```

(The parts without **  are optional.)

#### What's all that gobbledygook mean? Let's break it down.

1. `<img ... >` is the placeholder for an image.
2. `src="..."` tells the web browser where the image's data is stored or uploaded (its location, its URL).
3. `style="..."` style tells the web browser to expect a special set of codes called CSS (never mind what that is) which explain how you want the image to be displayed: its size, its layout, whether it has a border, and so on. Styles can also be added to set text colors, sizes and fonts. If HTML is the main chassis of the car, styles tells the web browser about the car's paint job and whether it comes equipped with bluetooth or cup holders.
4. `float: right;` means push the image as far to the right as it will go. If there's already something there (the sidebar, another floated image), then this image will squeeze in just to the left of that. This is how you tile images side by side. You can also float: left; to make images behave just like the letters of this paragraph: they'll start at the left-hand margin, then tile from left to right across the column until they run out of room, then they flow onto the next line.
5. `margin-left` and margin-bottom are optional. They add a little bit of an empty border (px means "pixels") to the left and under the image so things aren't mashed right up against it. If you have floated an image to the left, you should probably include a margin-right to add padding there.

**VERY IMPORTANT: TO TURN OFF "FLOAT", use the following command:**

`<p style="clear: both;">`

Why would you want to do that? Well, if an image is floated all the way to the right or left, whatever you write after that will attempt to fill in around it. For example, the text above filled in around that cat picture.

If you don't want the following paragraph to fill in next to the floated object, then you need to use the clear command to draw an invisible horizontal line across the page that says "everything after this has to start on a new paragraph, below the floated image(s)."

Comment: What if I wanted to add space between images so they aren't so closed to one another?

Comment: You could just edit `margin-left: 6px (or whatever works)`

Answer (score 0):

Add another img tag within the same `<td></td>`.

Try adding some external CSS styles to your rather than inline-CSS (Looks better and clear). Also make sure to give style for your image size.

If you would like your imges to be vertical aligned, try: `display:flex` and `flex-flow:column`

See snippet below:

```css
header {
  display: block;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
td {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<header class="header overlay" id="core_view_Header_0">
  <!-- visible bar -->
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a class="logo" href="#" target="" tabindex="12">
            <img src="~/img/logo1.png">
          </a>
          <a class="second-img" href="#" target="" tabindex="12">
            <img src="~/img/logo2.png">
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi I would need it horizontally aligned with a space between images

Comment: Then you just remove the styles for td (display: flex; flex-flow: column;) and add some paddings to the <a> link elements.